# If $x,y,z>0$ and $x+y+z=1$ then $\frac{xyz}{(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)}\le\frac{1}{8}$

Tags: inequality

**If** $x,y,z>0$ and $x+y+z=1$,
**then:** $$\frac{xyz}{(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)}\le\frac{1}{8}$$

---

$$\frac{xyz}{(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)}=\frac{x}{(1-x)}\frac{y}{(1-y)}\frac{z}{(1-z)}$$
Let $\frac{x}{(1-x)}=a$, $\frac{y}{(1-y)}=b$, $\frac{z}{(1-z)}=c$
I am stuck here.

Comment: Hint: $1-x = y+z \ge 2\sqrt{yz}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have: $$x+y+z=1$$
So, write: $$1-x=y+z$$
Using inequality $AP\geq GP$, $$y+z\geq 2\sqrt{yz}$$
So, $$(1-x)\geq2 \sqrt{yz}$$ Similarly,  $$(1-y)\geq2 \sqrt{xz} \hspace{0.5cm} {and} \hspace{0.5cm}  (1-z)\geq2 \sqrt{xy}$$
Multiplying all: $$(1-x)\cdot (1-y) \cdot (1-z) \geq 8 \cdot xyz$$

> **Divide:**$$\frac{(1-x)\cdot (1-y)\cdot (1-z)}{xyz}\geq 8$$ **Or,**
>    $$\frac{xyz}{(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)}\leq \frac 1 8$$ **In-equality will be reversed on dividing (why?)**

Answer (score 4):

Write $8xyz\le (x+y)(y+z)(x+z)$ and use arithmetic geometric inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.- Just to give another way. Developing the product and simplify you have the equivalent inequality
$$7xyz\le xy+xz+yz$$ and you have too $$\frac13\ge\sqrt[3]{xyz}$$

Comment: first line should be $\color{red}{9}xyz \le xy+xz+yz$.

Comment: That is right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you can separate variables in a simple way a good try is by convexity/concavity. In this case you can take the logarithm and use Jensen on the function
$$\log\left(\frac{x} {1-x}\right)$$
which you can prove to be concave by taking the second derivative.